# How to get the image base value of a .NET module in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, manifest

I'm programming a library that generates .NET assembly's manifests and I need to get the image base value of the assembly's modules. How can I get it in C#?

Comment: What is an "image base value"?  If we have to Google to find out what that means, you can probably Google to get the answer yourself.

Comment: Do you mean the [preferred base address of a DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1awdekb.aspx)?

Comment: I think he means `ImageBase`, which ILDASM will provide [if you ask it to.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ceats605.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to read the Portable Executable Header of the DLL or EXE.  Instructions for doing that can be found here:

**Reading the Portable Executable (PE) header in C#** 
http://code.cheesydesign.com/?p=572

`ImageBase` is located in `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32 {
  public UInt16 Magic;
  public Byte MajorLinkerVersion;
  public Byte MinorLinkerVersion;
  public UInt32 SizeOfCode;
  public UInt32 SizeOfInitializedData;
  public UInt32 SizeOfUninitializedData;
  public UInt32 AddressOfEntryPoint;
  public UInt32 BaseOfCode;
  public UInt32 BaseOfData;
  public UInt32 ImageBase;         <------------------ Here
  public UInt32 SectionAlignment;
  public UInt32 FileAlignment;
  public UInt16 MajorOperatingSystemVersion;
  public UInt16 MinorOperatingSystemVersion;
  public UInt16 MajorImageVersion;
  public UInt16 MinorImageVersion;
  public UInt16 MajorSubsystemVersion;
  public UInt16 MinorSubsystemVersion;
  public UInt32 Win32VersionValue;
  public UInt32 SizeOfImage;
  public UInt32 SizeOfHeaders;
  public UInt32 CheckSum;
  public UInt16 Subsystem;
  public UInt16 DllCharacteristics;
  public UInt32 SizeOfStackReserve;
  public UInt32 SizeOfStackCommit;
  public UInt32 SizeOfHeapReserve;
  public UInt32 SizeOfHeapCommit;
  public UInt32 LoaderFlags;
  public UInt32 NumberOfRvaAndSizes;
}
```